# Add chapter links to a video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I am fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery, but I have a video(video-tag) in my webpage and a bunch of links on the left side. Now the links should act as chapters.

So if I click on a chapter, the video should jump to a specific time in the video.

Is there a good solution which solves my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: want things did you find related to it

Comment: Show your Code what you tried till now

Comment: why can't you just use any server side scripting language and pass ID of video which pulls video path from db and play video for you on same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the HTML 5 video api and its `currentTime` property.
With this you can jump to a given time within a video (in seconds).

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement).

You would use it like this:

```
var myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo'),
    chpt1 = document.getElementById('chpt1');

chpt1.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    myvideo.play();
    myvideo.pause();
    myvideo.currentTime = 7; // or whatever
    myvideo.play();
}, false);
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sCvxm/1/) demonstrating this, taken from the following thread: [html5 video button that takes video to specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025378/html5-video-button-that-takes-video-to-specific-time)