# Start time for HTML5 Video using M3U8 playlist

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

How can I set the start time for a video source that is .m3u8. It works if the video is .mp4 when I append #t=3 to the URL but not for .m3u8 playlist, how can I set the start time for .m3u8 file?

**Works for MP4**

```
<video controls autoplay> 
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4#t=2">
</video>
```

**Not working for for M3U8**

```
<video controls autoplay> 
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.m3u8#t=2"  type="application/x-mpegurl">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any universally supported way of doing this beyond a javascript fix. I would listen for the `canplay` event in javascript and then adjust the playback position and start playback.

Mozilla's MDN site has a great overview of the [events generated by HTML 5 Video tags.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)

For how to jump to a specific time, see this this answer: [html5 video button that takes video to specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025378/html5-video-button-that-takes-video-to-specific-time)